# How to change the class of an href inside an li using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, href

i am new to jquery. I did read up on some methods to target the li but not getting how i can target the href inside a li to change the class of the selected menu. The code is as below:

```
<ul class="cssmenu">
    <li class="home">
        <a href="#" class="selected" title="Home">
            <span class="displace">
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="blog">
        <a href="#" title="Blog">
            <span class="displace">
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="contact">
        <a href="#" title="Contact">
            <span class="displace">
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the script I am using is

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() 
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("selected")
        .prependTo($this.parent())
        .siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Regardless of any other errors it should be $(this) and not $this

Comment: @LeeTaylor, please see that he redefined the `$this=$(this)`

Comment: You can't change the class of a `href`, that's an attribute, not an element; you *can*, however, change the class-name of an anchor (`a`) element (which I suspect you're trying to do). So: you want to click on an `a` element, and change the class of that element to `selected`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you bind the click event to the list item, you need to first use find() to remove the class from all the child anchors from the list items, and then add the selected class to the specific anchor child of the list (or anchor) you clicked on.

```
 $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
     $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass("selected");
     $('a',this).addClass("selected");
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3q2kQ/)**